# How to know that specific document is present in Cloudant Database using Android App

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, cloudant, nosql

I have successfully created document in Cloudant database through my Android App. But I can not find a specific document present in Cloudant database. What I have tried is like below....

TabTwo_Fragment.java

```
package com.example.android02.insightapp11;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cloudant.sync.datastore.BasicDocumentRevision;
import com.cloudant.sync.datastore.Datastore;
import com.cloudant.sync.datastore.DatastoreManager;
import com.cloudant.sync.datastore.DatastoreNotCreatedException;
import com.cloudant.sync.datastore.DocumentBodyFactory;
import com.cloudant.sync.datastore.DocumentException;
import com.cloudant.sync.datastore.DocumentNotFoundException;
import com.cloudant.sync.datastore.DocumentRevision;
import com.cloudant.sync.datastore.MutableDocumentRevision;
import com.cloudant.sync.replication.Replicator;
import com.cloudant.sync.replication.ReplicatorBuilder;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TabTwo_Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private static final String DATASTORE_MANGER_DIR = "data";
    private static final String TASKS_DATASTORE_NAME = "tasks";

    Datastore DataStore;
    private Replicator PushReplicator, PullReplicator;
    DocumentRevision revision;

    static final String CLOUDANT_USER = "user_default";
    static final String CLOUDANT_DB = "database_name";
    static final String CLOUDANT_API_KEY = "api_key";
    static final String CLOUDANT_API_SECRET = "api_key_pwd";

    long TWITTER_ID = MainActivity.twitterID;
    String TWITTER_NAME = MainActivity.userName;

    Button btn_submit;
    Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, sp5, sp6, sp7, sp8;
    TextView ans_total;

    String user = "old";
    HashMap<String, String> qa_hashmap;

    public TabTwo_Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static TabTwo_Fragment newInstance() {
        return new TabTwo_Fragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabtwo_fragment, container, false);
        try {
            init(rootView);
        } catch (DocumentNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    void init(View rootView) throws DocumentException, URISyntaxException {
        Log.e("init: ", "in init");
        find_view_by_id(rootView);
        registerClickEvents();
        defaultConfig();
        checkForRegisteredUser();
    }

    void find_view_by_id(View rootView) {
        Log.e("find_view_by_id: ", "in find_view_by_id");
        btn_submit = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        sp1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp1);
        sp2 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp2);
        sp3 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp3);
        sp4 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp4);
        sp5 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp5);
        sp6 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp6);
        sp7 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp7);
        sp8 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp8);
        ans_total = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ans_total);
    }

    void registerClickEvents() {
        Log.e("registerClickEvents: ", "in registerClickEvents");
        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void defaultConfig() {
        Log.e("defaultConfig: ", "in defaultConfig");
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getContext(), R.xml.preferences, false);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        sharedPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        File path = getContext().getDir(DATASTORE_MANGER_DIR, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        DatastoreManager manager = new DatastoreManager(path.getAbsolutePath());

        try {
            DataStore = manager.openDatastore(TASKS_DATASTORE_NAME);
            setUriPlusReplicators();
        } catch (DatastoreNotCreatedException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Unable to open Datastore!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "URI Exception!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        try {
            setUriPlusReplicators();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        }
    }

    void setUriPlusReplicators() throws URISyntaxException {
        Log.e("setUriPlusReplicators: ", "in setUriPlusReplicators");
        URI uri = this.createServerUri();
        Log.e("URI: ", "" + uri);
        PushReplicator = ReplicatorBuilder.push().from(DataStore).to(uri).build();
        PushReplicator.getEventBus().register(this);
        PullReplicator = ReplicatorBuilder.pull().to(DataStore).from(uri).build();
        PullReplicator.getEventBus().register(this);
    }

    private URI createServerUri() throws URISyntaxException {
        Log.e("createServerUri: ", "in createServerUri");
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        String username = sharedPref.getString(CLOUDANT_USER, "");
        String dbName = sharedPref.getString(CLOUDANT_DB, "");
        String apiKey = sharedPref.getString(CLOUDANT_API_KEY, "");
        String apiSecret = sharedPref.getString(CLOUDANT_API_SECRET, "");
        String host = username + ".cloudant.com";
        return new URI("https", apiKey + ":" + apiSecret, host, 443, "/" + dbName, null, null);
    }

    private URI createServerUri2(long twitterId) throws URISyntaxException {
        Log.e("createServerUri2: ", "in createServerUri2");
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        String username = sharedPref.getString(CLOUDANT_USER, "");
        String dbName = sharedPref.getString(CLOUDANT_DB, "");
        String apiKey = sharedPref.getString(CLOUDANT_API_KEY, "");
        String apiSecret = sharedPref.getString(CLOUDANT_API_SECRET, "");
        String host = username + ".cloudant.com";
        return new URI("https", apiKey + ":" + apiSecret, host, 443, "/" + dbName + "/_all_docs?", null, null);
    }

    void checkForRegisteredUser() throws DocumentNotFoundException, DocumentException, URISyntaxException {
        BasicDocumentRevision retrieved = DataStore.getDocument(TWITTER_ID + "");
        if (user.equals("new")) {
            setQuizData(retrieved.getBody().toString());
        } else {
            newUser();
        }
    }

    void setQuizData(String DataRetrieved) {
        Log.e("setQuizData: ", "In setQuizData");
        user = "old";
        Log.e("DataRetrieved: ", "In " + DataRetrieved);
        String[] ANSWERS = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ans);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(DataRetrieved);
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("questions");
            String qs1 = jsonObject1.getString("q1");
            String qs2 = jsonObject1.getString("q2");
            String qs3 = jsonObject1.getString("q3");
            String qs4 = jsonObject1.getString("q4");
            String qs5 = jsonObject1.getString("q5");
            String qs6 = jsonObject1.getString("q6");
            String qs7 = jsonObject1.getString("q7");
            String qs8 = jsonObject1.getString("q8");

            sp1.setSelection(Arrays.asList(ANSWERS).indexOf(qs1));
            sp2.setSelection(Arrays.asList(ANSWERS).indexOf(qs2));
            sp3.setSelection(Arrays.asList(ANSWERS).indexOf(qs3));
            sp4.setSelection(Arrays.asList(ANSWERS).indexOf(qs4));
            sp5.setSelection(Arrays.asList(ANSWERS).indexOf(qs5));
            sp6.setSelection(Arrays.asList(ANSWERS).indexOf(qs6));
            sp7.setSelection(Arrays.asList(ANSWERS).indexOf(qs7));
            sp8.setSelection(Arrays.asList(ANSWERS).indexOf(qs8));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }

    void newUser() {
        Log.e("newUser: ", "In newUser");
        user = "new";
    }

    void createDocument() throws DocumentException {
        Log.e("createDocument: ", "In createDocument");
        MutableDocumentRevision rev = new MutableDocumentRevision();
        rev.docId = TWITTER_ID + "";
        gatherQAData();

        /*HashMap<String, Object> map_main = new HashMap<String, Object>();*/
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayTeachers = new ArrayList<>();

        map.put("twitter_id", TWITTER_ID + "");
        map.put("twitter_name", TWITTER_NAME);
        map.put("questions", qa_hashmap);
        /*arrayTeachers.add(map);*/
        /*map_main.put("user", arrayTeachers);*/

        rev.body = DocumentBodyFactory.create(map);
        revision = DataStore.createDocumentFromRevision(rev);
        PushReplicator.start();
    }

    void updateDocument() {
        Log.e("updateDocument: ", "In updateDocument");
    }

    void gatherQAData() {
        Log.e("gatherQAData: ", "In gatherQAData");
        qa_hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8;
        a1 = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        a2 = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        a3 = sp3.getSelectedItem().toString();
        a4 = sp4.getSelectedItem().toString();
        a5 = sp5.getSelectedItem().toString();
        a6 = sp6.getSelectedItem().toString();
        a7 = sp7.getSelectedItem().toString();
        a8 = sp8.getSelectedItem().toString();
        qa_hashmap.put("q1", a1);
        qa_hashmap.put("q2", a2);
        qa_hashmap.put("q3", a3);
        qa_hashmap.put("q4", a4);
        qa_hashmap.put("q5", a5);
        qa_hashmap.put("q6", a6);
        qa_hashmap.put("q7", a7);
        qa_hashmap.put("q8", a8);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_submit:
                if (user.equals("new")) {
                    try {
                        createDocument();
                    } catch (DocumentException e) {
                    }
                } else {
                    updateDocument();
                }
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Doc Stored in Cloudant DB]

I can get the document which is stored in DataStore. But I am unable to get document stored in Cloudant database.

FYI: I am finding document in `checkForRegisteredUser` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have done it. Below is my code for `checkForRegisteredUser` method of TabTwo_Fragment.java

```
void checkForRegisteredUser() {
        String url = "https://your_cloudant_user_name.cloudant.com/" + DB_NAME + "/" + DOC_ID;
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                if (response.toString().length() > 0) {
                    setQuizData(response.toString());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                newUser();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jor);
```

Here is s Official Documentation [LINK](https://docs.cloudant.com/document.html#read).

Here **DOC_ID** is the id of document that you want to check. Hope this will help to somebody.

Comment: I think this answer need improvement because you can not filter document with ID because us can not determine what id document is going to be, what question is talking about is he want to know if given supply data is exist before he insert it to database

Comment: I was giving **DOC_ID** as user's **fb_id** or **twitter_id**. So, If user Register first time no **DATA** was there and It will create it's document with that **fb_id** or **twitter_id**. Now, on Second time If that user **Login** that **DOC_ID** found because **DOC_ID** was given as **fb_id** or **twitter_id**.@Michael

Answer (score 0):

What happens in Cloudant is that there are already two fields by default given by cloudant to each document namely   _id and _rev where _id acts as primarykey for indexing. So there will be a default index created by cloudant on the _id field. If you already have these fields in your document than cloudant won't insert extra _id and _rev. 
Now you can have this _id field in your document and set it according to yourself or let cloudant set it. But when you are not setting it than you won't be able to query Cloudant on the primary index because you don't know the _id of the document.
So to search or find on basis of some other field like the twitter_id as you have stored you have to create one more index than you'll be able to search/find according to that.
we can create index in java using the function provided by cloudant api

```
public void createIndex(java.lang.String indexName,
               java.lang.String designDocName,
               java.lang.String indexType,
               IndexField[] fields)
```

or If you are assigning _id in your function than you can simply call a function

```
db.contains(doc_id);
```

which is a lot easier as you don't need to create any index and using default index.

EDIT-1
So the db here is the database instance you have acquired.

```
Database db=client.database(db_name,create_flag);
```

where **create_flag** is a **boolean** to if the database should be created if not existed so true means yes create false means no don't create if not there.
and client is CloudantClient object.
But alternatively you can call createDB also if you know the db is not there. You can do it as follow

```
Database db=client.createDB("DBNAME");
```

How to get a CloudantClient is dependent on the version of cloudant api you are using. for ex 1.0.1 is different from the latest.
in version 1.0.1 you do it as follow

```
CloudantClient client=new CloudantClient(URL_OF_YOUR_CLOUDANT,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
```

But in latest release they use

```
CloudantClient client=ClientBuilder.url(new URL("your url")).username("your username string").password("your password").build();
```

SO I don't know why you were not able to find createIndex. I suppose you are unable to find Cloudant-api javadocs .Just google for Cloudant javadocs or check this github
[GitHub link](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant)

Comment: What is **db** here? And second thing, I dont find any `createIndex` function provided by cloudant api.@H S Rathore

Comment: Your answer doesn't resolve to your question plus the answer you have given is not even using any cloudant library. My answer is way better than yours still you accept your own answer.